# Google Maps - Is there an API method or service that given latitude and longitude, determine if that location is inside a Polygon

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

Is there an API method or service that given latitude and longitude, determine if that location is inside a Polygon?

I know there is way in javascript using [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), but is there a way to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://www.assemblysys.com/dataServices/php_pointinpolygon.php) has some php code that determines if a point lies within a polygon.  Note that it works with strings to begin with; just skip the translation function if you already have float numbers.

Comment: Please refer: https://github.com/alexpechkarev/geometry-library